# Create checkbox programmatically in Fragment

Tags: android, android-checkbox, programmatically-created

I am trying to create a checkbox in my Fragment. I dont get it to work right.
Here is my code for the Fragment:

```
 public class DriverFragment extends Fragment {

    public DriverFragment(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CheckBox check = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        check.setText("ff");
        check.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
        check.setLayoutParams(params);
        check.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.driverLayout);
        lin.addView(check);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driver,container,false);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> > Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Do I get this because the view with the LinearLayout has not been loaded yet?

Comment: add your `R.layout.fragment_driver` too?

Comment: What do you mean? Dont understand. Add the R.layout.fragment_driver to what?

Comment: Your checkbox creation code should be in `onCreateView()` method because your view inflate in that.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have moved it to >>onCreateView() and I get the same error

Comment: Check answer of @SohailZahid . It is correct answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See **Fragment life cycle** you cant get view widgets in `OnCreate()` because its inflating in `OnCreateView();`

[image]

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driver, container, false);

        CheckBox check = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        check.setText("ff");
        check.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
        check.setLayoutParams(params);
        check.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.driverLayout);
        lin.addView(check);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: @mrg3tools Thats great if it help please tick mark and vote up.

Comment: @mrg3tools No problem. happy coding :)